# How to get number of occurrences in pandas dataframe with a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like following:

```
 product  stars
  10717  4
  10717  5
  10717  5
  10717  5
  10717  3
  10717  2
  10717  2
  10711  2
  10711  1
  10711  5
  10711  1
  10711  1
  10711  5
  10711  2
```

I have thousands rows.
I want to calculate for each distinct product the number of occurences of each star (from 1 to 5).

How can I achieve this?

What I tried is to get the list of the distinct products with:
`dp = df.product.unique()`  
Than I looped over it:

```
for key in dd:    
    sf_1[(sf_1['product'] == key)].value_counts()
```

The result looks like:

```
product  stars
10717        5         3
             4         1
             3         1
             2         2
dtype: int64

product  stars
10711        5        2
             2        3
             1        2
dtype: int64
```

What I need is a new dataframe which looks like

```
product     stars    number_stars
10717         5        3
10717         4        1
10717         3        1
10717         2        2 
10717         1        0
10711         5        2
10711         4        0
10711         3        0
10711         2        3
10711         1        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupby` and `.size` do the counting of the number of stars per product. Lines 2 and 3 are just formatting the data to get it to look like you showed in the question, you may not actually need them.

```
df.groupby(["product", "stars"]).size() \
  .unstack(fill_value=0).stack() \
  .to_frame("number_stars").reset_index()

   product  stars  number_stars
0    10711      1             3
1    10711      2             2
2    10711      3             0
3    10711      4             0
4    10711      5             2
5    10717      1             0
6    10717      2             2
7    10717      3             1
8    10717      4             1
9    10717      5             3
```

Comment: This solution is so elegant and it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) (the `reindex` and `MultiIndex` part is only needed to get the zero counts):

```
stars = list(range(1,6))
cols = ['product', 'stars']

(df.value_counts(cols)
 .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['product'].unique(),stars], names=cols),
          fill_value=0)
 .rename('number_stars').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   product  stars  number_stars
0    10717      1             0
1    10717      2             2
2    10717      3             1
3    10717      4             1
4    10717      5             3
5    10711      1             3
6    10711      2             2
7    10711      3             0
8    10711      4             0
9    10711      5             2
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  [10717,  4],
  [10717,  5],
  [10717,  5],
  [10717,  5],
  [10717,  3],
  [10717,  2],
  [10717,  2],
  [10711,  2],
  [10711,  1],
  [10711,  5],
  [10711,  1],
  [10711,  1],
  [10711,  5],
  [10711,  2]
  ],columns=['product','stars']
  )
  
newdf = df.groupby(['product','stars']).size()
newdf = newdf.reset_index()
newdf = newdf.rename(columns={0:'number_stars'})
```

result:

```
>>> newdf
   product  stars  number_stars
0    10711      1             3
1    10711      2             2
2    10711      5             2
3    10717      2             2
4    10717      3             1
5    10717      4             1
6    10717      5             3
```

Comment: OP wants 0 counts as well